# Swift UI Component in ScrollView can't be detected

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, scrollview

I have an UIView in the ScrollView. But the every component in this UIVIew and even itself cannot detect the gestures.

I have to use the textfield for input the nickname, and also have to tap the UIView for able/disable the male/female gender status.

And here is my code. Even I have tried other solution found on Internet, it is still not working.

```
let tapViewMale = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tapViewMale.addTarget(self, action:#selector(viewMaleClicked))
    self.viewMain!.addGestureRecognizer(tapViewMale)
    let tapViewFemale = UITapGestureRecognizer()#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Screen Shot 2017-11-09 at 12.15.55 PM.png")
    tapViewFemale.addTarget(self, action:#selector(viewFemaleClicked(_:)))
    self.checkboxFemale.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.checkboxFemale.addGestureRecognizer(tapViewFemale)
}

@objc func viewMaleClicked(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print ("viewMaleClicked")
    if gender == "" || gender == "F" {
        print ("1")
        checkboxMale.image = UIImage(named: "checked_checkbox")
        checkboxFemale.image = UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox")
        gender = "M"
    } else {
        print ("2")
        checkboxMale.image = UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox")
        gender = ""
    }
}

@objc func viewFemaleClicked(_ sender:AnyObject) {
    print ("viewFemaleClicked")
    if gender == "" || gender == "M" {
        print ("1")
        checkboxFemale.image = UIImage(named: "checked_checkbox")
        checkboxMale.image = UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox")
        gender = "F"
    } else {
        print ("2")
        checkboxFemale.image = UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox")
        gender = ""
    }
}
```

Here are the screenshots.

[image: full component tree]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Implement `func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool { return true }` as your `tapGesture.delegate` and `scrollView.delegate`.. It will return true allowing multiple gestures (the scroll gesture + other gestures like your tap-gesture)..  Then set `userInteractionEnabled = true` on the views that need taps recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easy way to use transparent button instead of giving gesture to uiview inside scrollView.

```
@IBAction func onClickBtnMale(_ sender: Any)
    { if gender == "" || gender == "F" {
        print ("1")
        checkboxMale.image = UIImage(named: "checked_checkbox")
        checkboxFemale.image = UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox")
        gender = "M"
    } else {
        print ("2")
        checkboxMale.image = UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox")
        gender = ""
    }
}
```

- You can make equal width of uibutton to your view and use it for tap.

Comment: I'm sorry that I haven't explained it in detail. The labels and the buttons are not transparent. I have set the text programmatically by using LocalizableString.
And gesture to the UIView doesn't work neither.

Comment: No i mean to say take another transparent button and give click event to that

Comment: take the button which actually size of your view inside that view so click event of that button is called

Comment: i got your word now. But how about the textfield? it can't be touched and be focused on the scrollview.

Comment: are you sure your mainview has user interaction enabled because scroll cant stop interacting user with textfiled.

Comment: Yes. I have uploaded the screenshots. All the uiviews and scrollview are unabled for the user interaction field.

Comment: remove tapGesture for male and female gesture and any other gesture you have given completly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158565/discussion-between-jaydeep-vyas-and-young-jun-choi).